# Migrating questions to codereview

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions, declined-flags

I recently nominated a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230101/how-could-i-make-this-r-snippet-faster-and-more-r-ish) for migration to Code Review.SE. The question title

> How could I make this R snippet faster and more R-ish

clearly indicates that it is on scope for codereview. The question is new. However on flagging, the mod declined with the statement:

```
If an on-topic question is getting answers here, 
we shouldn't migrate them to a less active site.
```

This just seems a bit odd.

1. Stack Exchange is creating new sites all the time. The vast majority of people don't keep track of this explosion.
2. For codereview in particular, any questions on a particular language will get a (good/better?) answer here. Therefore, why have codereview?

Comment: I am not sure why there is no option to migrate to codereview through the close-offtopic-migrate menu. But [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405930/chines-restaurant-process-implementation-in-python) sure does fit the bill.

Answer (score 8):

Because you don't want to push on-topic content away. It's [considered rude](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

> When evaluating a question, **you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site**; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. Be a bit jealous of your site – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

Ideally, let an on-topic question stay where it is. You can post a comment informing the OP about Code Review, but **not** in the form of

> ask on codereview.SE

Instead, something like:

> We have a site specialized on Code Review. If your question doesn't get too much attention or the answers are insufficient, you can request to migrate it there by clicking "Flag", and informing a moderator

Then, the OP can decide where to keep their questions. Don't forget that some deliberately choose to ask their questions on the site they're most familiar with.

It should be the duty of Code Review to create their own community. You don't create this community by constantly migrating stuff from other sites, as long as these questions are not off-topic for the sites they were migrated from.

Similar discussion on Meta.SU about migrating on-topic Apple questions to Apple.SE: [Is it okay to inform users to stop promoting Apple.SE when a question is fine to stay here?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to)

> The only times a user should be encouraged to have their question migrated to [insert SE site here] are if the question is one of the following:
>
> - off topic here, but on topic there
> - getting very few views and no good answers, and you believe it might get better answers there
>   the user who asks the question requests it to be moved because they think it would do better there

Comment: I take your point (and agree). However, just to be awkward, are code review questions on scope for SO. Looking at the [http://stackoverflow.com/faq][FAQ], code review questions sort of fall under "practical, answerable problems.." But code review isn't a question. It's "Please review my code"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on that. If a moderator said so, well, here's your answer – But I agree, I personally wouldn't say they're on-topic for SO.